# Getting Error connecting to Elasticsearch in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, nestjs

I set up ElasticSearch in nestjs using ElasticSearch Module but I am geting this error shown on the title.
After lot of debugging, I found that options is passsed as undefined in the ElasticSearchService file in the @nestjs/elasticsearch package

What should I do ?

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ElasticsearchModule } from '@nestjs/elasticsearch';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { SearchModule } from './search/search.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(), // Make sure this line is present
    ElasticsearchModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        node: configService.get('ELASTICSEARCH_NODE'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    SearchModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

ERROR:

```
[Nest] 470882  - 06/06/2023, 8:08:10 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cloud')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cloud')
    at new Client (/home/oem/Documents/nestjs-starter/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/src/client.ts:128:15)
    at new ElasticsearchService (/home/oem/Documents/nestjs-starter/node_modules/@nestjs/elasticsearch/dist/elasticsearch.service.js:21:9)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (/home/oem/Documents/nestjs-starter/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:340:19)
    at callback (/home/oem/Documents/nestjs-starter/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:53:45)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/home/oem/Documents/nestjs-starter/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:132:24)
    at Injector.loadInstance (/home/oem/Documents/nestjs-starter/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:57:13)
    at Injector.loadProvider (/home/oem/Documents/nestjs-starter/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:84:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (/home/oem/Documents/nestjs-starter/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:44:9)
    at /home/oem/Documents/nestjs-starter/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:29:13
```

Comment: are you sure that `configService.get('ELASTICSEARCH_NODE')` is what do you think it is? try hard coding that value instead of using `configService`

Comment: @MicaelLevi Yes, I hardcoded the value as well. Still getting same error. Actually the issue is the options are passed undefined in ElasticSearchService Class.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, actually the `ElasticSearchService` was imported in another module inside a folder. `src/search/search.module.ts`
So I moved the `ElasticSearchModule` inside the folder where `ElasticSearchService (src/search/search.module.ts)` was imported as a provider

It is possible that `ElasticSearchService` was injecting before the configuration of `ElasticSearchModule` in `app.module.ts`

Comment: Can you please show us the code after the fix.

Comment: There is an example in the Discord, now: https://discord.com/channels/520622812742811698/1146114365846720674/1162144773424037939

Comment: @Tayan the fix was adding ```ElasticsearchModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        node: configService.get('ELASTICSEARCH_NODE'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),``` inside `search.module.ts` instead of `app.module.ts`. that's it!